# Grammatical status of Question tags in Sentences

Tags: descriptive-grammar

When a question tag is added to a simple sentence, what does the combined sentence become? (compound sentence/complex sentence)

1. Can it be classified as asyndetic co-ordinate clause?
2. If question tag clause is classified as dependent clause, then obviously the sentence becomes a complex sentence, doesn't it? So, in that case, which category (Noun/Adjective/Adverb) of dependent clause will question tag fall in?

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding about this. Clauses don't belong to the parts of speech like noun, adjective etc., but are classified by type such as finite (relative / comparative / content) and non-finite (infinitival / gerund-participial / past participial), and then by function such as modifier / complement / supplement. A tag is a truncated interrogative clause functioning as a supplement and hence is a subordinate (dependent) clause, so I suppose you could call the sentence a complex one.

Comment: Dear Bill,  The subordinate clause in a complex sentence is either working as a Noun,Adjective or Adverb and since they have a Subject and a finite verb, they are called Clause as per most of the traditional Grammar books. Hence this category of interrogative clause i have not come across in any Grammar book.What you refer as The non finite clauses are basically labelled as phrases in our understanding .Hence,  the difference in perspective. It the tag is supplement, does it become Noun clause subordinate to main clause of the sentence. Seeking your elaboration. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, your understanding is so remote from reality that I cannot help you any further.

Comment: I think you should have asked your question on  our sister site ELL which is more suited to non-native speakers. [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What do you mean by "asyndetic"? I can't work out what word that should be.

Comment: Asyndetic is the act of leaving a required conjunction. Like"He needs food, water("and" conjunction has been  left in this sentence